# Using React and Web Components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, web-component

In our project we are using React and Web Components to develop reusable UI components (which in turn will be used by various dev teams internally). Components are developed in React and registered as custom HTML elements through Web Components. We need a way through which we can define the props in HTML custom tag and access all the props in our React Component.

The HTML would be like

```
<custom-element props1='pageInfo' props2='mediaInfo'></custom-element>
```

`pageInfo` and `mediaInfo` will be JS Objects which will be declared in global window scope or they can be inside some other NameSpace/Object, in that case the HTML would be something like

```
<custom-element props1='NS.pageInfo' props2='NS.mediaInfo'></custom-element>
```

OR

```
<custom-element props1='NS.Page.pageInfo' props2='NS.Media.mediaInfo'></custom-element>
```

So, we **need a way to get all the props defined in the HTML and resolve them as Objects and pass it on to `ReactDOM.render`**

Currently the code to render and register custom element is,

```
class RegComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    createdCallback() {
        ReactDOM.render(<App props1={eval(this.getAttributes('props1'))}/>, this);
    }
}
document.registerElement('custom-element', RegComponent);
```

We want to get rid of eval and all the declared props should be fetched from HTML and passed on to `ReactDOM.render`. Looking for something like,

```
ReactDOM.render(<App {getAllProps()}/>, this);
```

where `getAllProps()` should return all the props name & their value. Remember that I'm using ES6. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey @Aleem, we are also trying to render React components as web components and did it similar to your way, but we are missing one thing: the CSS. How do you write CSS so that it will be integrated in your web component?

Comment: @Lukas We write styles in SASS, use Webpack to transpile and bundle into separate CSS file. You can also try 'styled components', 'radium' etc.

Comment: You could use this as guide, and also what @falsarella answers about using JS instead of JSX

Comment: Anyone make any progress on this ?

Answer (score 2):

What about instead of using JSX:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App props1={eval(this.getAttributes('props1'))}/>, this);
```

Use React directly, with an adapter transforming attributes into props:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, {...getAllProps(this.attributes)}), this);

function getAllProps(attributes) {
    var props = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        props[attributes[i].nodeName] = attributes[i].nodeValue;
    }
    return props;
}
```

Comment: And If you want to use it the other way, you can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175599/how-to-use-react-inside-a-polymer-component/45550646#45550646

Answer (score 0):

If `getAllProps()` returns an object, and each property in the object is the prop you wanted, you should only need to update you render to use the spread operator(`...`). This will deconstruct your object so that each property is passed to the `App` as a `prop`.

Here is what it would look like:

`ReactDOM.render(<App {...getAllProps()}/>, this);`

Comment: I agree with the spread operator, but the main issue here is actually how to implement that `getAllProps()`, not how to use it.