# How to use react inside a polymer component?

Tags: reactjs, polymer, web-component

It seems it could posible to use react inside a polymer web component but I couldn’t find a working example, only [this](http://codepen.io/mcondon/pen/HKtBq), but it seems outdated.

**HTML**

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<polymer-element name="my-polymer" constructor="" attributes="name">
    <template>
      <P>I AM {{name}}</P>
      <div id="reactContainer"></div>
    </template>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      /** @jsx React.DOM **/
      Polymer('my-polymer', {
        created: function(){},
        ready: function(){},
        attached: function(){},
        domReady: function(){
          React.renderComponent(<MyReact name="REACT INSIDE POLYMER"/>, this.$.reactContainer);
        },
        detached: function(){},
        attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {}
      });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
<my-polymer name="POLYMER"></my-polymer>
```

**JS**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
  var MyReact = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <p>I AM {this.props.name}</p>    
      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using React and Web Components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026656/using-react-and-web-components)

Answer (score 3):

The main things you gotta take care of before, is:

- transform the **index.jsx** into **index.js** *javacript form* (https://github.com/jsx/JSX)

  - `babel --plugins transform-react-jsx`
- Bundle up your reactApp with  Traceur Compiler, Babel, Rollup or webPack. Since imports aren't yet implemented in browsers.

  - make sure you main file **index.js**, doesn't render's react. That's going to be Polymer's responsibility.
  - `npm run build` (obtained with `npm run build` for reac-redux)

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './components/App'
import reducer from './reducers'

window.Render = render;
window.React = React;
window.CreateStore = createStore;
window.Provider = Provider;
window.App = App;
window.Reducer = reducer;
```

**example-component.html**

```
  <link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">

  <dom-module id="example-component">
    <template>
    </template>

    <script src="./main.bundleFromReact.js"></script>

    <script>
     class ExampleComponent extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'example-component'; }

        ready() {
          super.ready();
          const store = CreateStore(Reducer);

          Render(
            React.createElement(
              Provider,
              {store: store},
              React.createElement(
                App,
                null
              )
            ),
            this.shadowRoot
          );
        }
      }
      window.customElements.define(ExampleComponent.is, ExampleComponent);
      </script>
   </dom-module>
```

**tl;dr**

You can see my simplest example without importing here:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">
<script src="../react/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="../react/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<dom-module id="example-component">
   <template></template>

   <script>
     class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
       render() {
         return React.createElement(
           'div',
           {}, `Hello ${this.props.name}`);
       }
     }

     class ExampleComponent extends Polymer.Element {
     static get is() { return 'example-component'; }

     ready() {
       super.ready();

       var mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
       this.shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);

       ReactDOM.render(
         React.createElement(HelloMessage, {name: 'Maestro'}),
         mountPoint
       );
     }
  }

  window.customElements.define(ExamplComponent.is, ExamplComponent);
</script>
```

Comment: Trying to get CSS to work with this, but it seems this wipes out any styling applied to the Polymer component. Any suggestions?

Comment: So polymer uses the shadow DOM, which encapsulates the CSS. So global CSS won't be applied into the polymer's component. Therefore any external CSS won't be applied into the react inside polymer. But you can use mixins to import styles into the polymer/react component (https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-css-properties#use-custom-css-mixins) ... And most importantly, please let me know if I miss understood you

Comment: Well, it seems the ReactDOM.render() method actually re-writes the DOM, so when you apply CSS to the element in a polymer way it wipes out the `<style>` element. (I didn't try mixins because the CSS is from a 3rd party library). FOR NOW.. I've manually added in the CSS retroactively using vanilla JS. I'm not happy with it, but it works haha. Thank you!